# How can I query a computer for the "Last Checked" information of Windows Update?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-registry, windows-update

The Windows Update page in Settings contains a `Last Checked` timestamp, and I am trying to determine if it is possible to somehow query a machine for this information (by way of Command Prompt, PowerShell,  Registry query, etc.)

I searched the `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate` part of my registry and found no stored date that matched the value of my `Last Checked`.

Is there any way to query for this? The goal is to be able to query a remote computer for the information so as to avoid having to remote into it.

[image]

Running the PowerShell command `$(New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate).Results.LastSearchSuccessDate` returns a timestamp with matching date, but mismatched time

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested, converting the UTC time returned by `LastSearchSuccessDate` to your local time using a (.NET) function :

```
Function Get-LocalTime($UTCTime) {
    $strCurrentTimeZone = (Get-WmiObject win32_timezone).StandardName
    $TZ = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById($strCurrentTimeZone)
    Return [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeFromUtc($UTCTime, $TZ)
}

Get-LocalTime $(New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate).Results.LastSearchSuccessDate
```

Gives me the same result as shown in the 'Check for updates' UI.

#### Remote Execution

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { 
    Function Get-LocalTime($UTCTime) {
    $strCurrentTimeZone = (Get-WmiObject win32_timezone).StandardName
    $TZ = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById($strCurrentTimeZone)
    Return [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeFromUtc($UTCTime, $TZ)
    }
    
    Get-LocalTime $(New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate).Results.LastSearchSuccessDate
};
```

Comment: One-liner for those that don't want variables or functions in the command being invoked.... `[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeFromUtc($(New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate).Results.LastSearchSuccessDate, [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById((Get-WmiObject win32_timezone).StandardName))`